# unix sed to replace line only if whole word exists

Tags: unix, sed

I have three lines in a text

`clm_id double,
actv_clm_id double,
clm_id int,`

I want to replace the line where the whole word clm_id occurs to following

`clm_id bigint,
actv_clm_id double,
clm_id bigint,`

Any pointers?

Comment: Give clear input and desired output. Learn regexes. Lookup sed tutorials. ;)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did it not work?

Comment: This is what I was trying `sed -i 's/\<clm_id\>/c\/clm_id bigint,/gI' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\<clm_id\>/c\clm_id bigint,' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command:

```
sed 's/.*\(^\| \)clm_id\( \|$\).*/clm_id bigint/' input.file
```

**Explanation:**

```
/         Delimiter

.*        Anything (optional)

\(^\| \)  Selects the beginning of the line `^` or `|` a whitespace before the word.
          into a capturing group (Note that `(|)` need to get escaped by a `\'

clm_id    Selects clm_id

\( \|$\)  ... followed by a whitespace or the end of the line `$`

.*        Anything (optional)

/         Delimiter
```

**Output:**

```
clm_id bigint
actv_clm_id double
clm_id bigint
```

Comment: I think OP wants to replace lines that match a pattern, not delete them entirely.

Comment: Yes, checked that (now). Updated my post